# Accessing original field in Parse.com Cloud Code beforeSave function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

The ultimate goal is to detect changes between an existing Parse object and the incoming update using the `beforeSave` function in Cloud Code.

From the Cloud Code log available through parse.com, one can see the input to `beforeSave` contains a field called `original` and another one called `update`.

Cloud Code log:

```
Input: {"original": { ... }, "update":{...}
```

I wonder if, and how, we can access the original field in order to detect changing fields before saving.

Note that I've already tried several approaches for solving this without success:

- using (object).changedAttributes()
- using (object).previousAttributes()
- fetching the existing object, before updating it with the new data

Note on `request.object.changedAttributes()`:
returns `false` when using in beforeSave and afterSave -- see below for more details:

Log for `before_save` -- summarised for readability:

```
Input: { original: {units: '10'}, update: {units: '11'} }
Result: Update changed to { units: '11' }
[timestamp] false <--- console.log(request.object.changedAttributes())
```

Log for corresponding `after_save`:

```
[timestamp] false <--- console.log(request.object.changedAttributes())
```

Comment: `object.changedAttributes()` is the correct approach.  Please post your attempt related to that, and we'll make it work.

Comment: `request.object.changedAttributes()` returns `false`

Comment: If you can produce a demonstration of that (changing an object, then finding `changedAttributes() === false`), then you'll have found a parse.com bug.  I suspect, though, that you're mistaken.  Please prove me wrong by posting a failure others can reproduce.

Comment: Added details on the case I'm talking about. Note that I'm talking about Cloud Code, and not using the JS SDK on the client side.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE).  Say, a class with one attribute, an afterSave hook for that class that logs changedAttributes and client code that changes the one attribute and does a save.  Prove that the client makes the change, prove that the afterSave doesn't see changedAttributes.  If you can prove it, you'll have found a bug in parse, but almost certainly, you'll discover your original mistake while building the MRE.

Comment: PS - I ask SO questioners for an MRE every so often, and 9.5 times out of 10, its the last activity seen on the question.  I figure that this is because (a) good outcome: doing the MRE will often lead the questioner to the answer, or (b) bad outcome, the questioner is unwilling to put in the MRE effort, and just drops it.

Comment: I don't see the point of including client code since the parse.com cloud code log recognizes that an update has occurred.

Comment: client code, because maybe you're mistaken to think that you actually changed the object.  and server code, please.  code+logs is the only way to see what's happening.

Comment: If the object did not change, parse.com should not recognise that update has occurred as an output of Cloud Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81996/discussion-between-danh-and-marco-alves).

Comment: My apologies.  I assumed you had a bug and just blamed parse.  I decided, arrogantly, that if you were too lazy to build an MRE, I would do it and show you the error in your ways.  Imagine my surprise to find the same issue!  Sorry again.  As penance, I built a work-around and posted it below.

Comment: @danh Thank you for your willingness to going the extra mile and for the work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a problem with `changedAttributes()`.  It seems to answer false all the time -- or at least in `beforeSave`, where it would reasonably be needed. (See [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-get-the-changed-attribute-value-beforesave), as well as other similar posts)

Here's a general purpose work-around to do what changedAttributes ought to do.

```
// use underscore for _.map() since its great to have underscore anyway
// or use JS map if you prefer...

var _ = require('underscore');

function changesOn(object, klass) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(klass);
    return query.get(object.id).then(function(savedObject) {
        return _.map(object.dirtyKeys(), function(key) {
            return { oldValue: savedObject.get(key), newValue: object.get(key) }
        });
    });
}

// my mre beforeSave looks like this
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Dummy", function(request, response) {
    var object = request.object;
    var changedAttributes = object.changedAttributes();
    console.log("changed attributes = " + JSON.stringify(changedAttributes));  // null indeed!

    changesOn(object, "Dummy").then(function(changes) {
        console.log("DIY changed attributes = " + JSON.stringify(changes));
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

When I change `someAttribute` (a number column on a `Dummy` instance) from 32 to 1222 via client code or data browser, the log shows this:

> I2015-06-30T20:22:39.886Z]changed attributes = false
>
> I2015-06-30T20:22:39.988Z]DIY changed attributes =
>   [{"oldValue":32,"newValue":1222}]