# read the object from beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve/fetch a current object from the `beforeSave` method as I want to know the value of "Parent" column before update was initiated.

I used the below code. However, I see that older values and newer values remain equal though value of "Parent" has been changed through data browser.

Is there any suggestion to read the current object from `beforeSave`? Is anything going wrong below?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Products", function(request, response) {
    var oldObject = new Parse.Object('Products');
    oldObject.id = "RTRzAf1FyX"; // RTRzAf1FyX is equal to request.object.id. oldObject.id is being hard coded to RTRzAf1FyX

    listOfAllPromisesForCurrentObject.push(oldObject.fetch());

    Parse.Promise.when(listOfAllPromisesForCurrentObject).then(function(currentObject) {

      console.log("11111 +++++++++++++++" + JSON.stringify( request.object.get('Parent')) ); //Parent is a column name
      console.log("11111 ---------------" + JSON.stringify( currentObject.get('Parent')) );

});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100446/accessing-original-field-in-parse-com-cloud-code-beforesave-function

Answer (score 0):

You can't get those old values. Only whether or not the key is dirty. The only suggestion I have is to have two pointers, parent and oldParent, and when you're updating parent, do oldParent = parent first.

Comment: Untrue, I think.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100446/accessing-original-field-in-parse-com-cloud-code-beforesave-function

Comment: @danh No , it did not work. In fact, Your solution depends on "query.get(object.id)." returning a old value.   However , that's not happening in the latest parse release. Not Sure about Parse's earlier behaviour.

Comment: It appears that @jake-t suggestion is the only way out , for this problem. Would be glad if some other solution exists.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the oldParent pointer in the beforeSave trigger after you're done using it, to avoid fetching/saving an extra object when you fetch/save the Products object.